# .htaccess url rewrite rules problems

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need some help to write a rewrite rule : I tested many many things but i guess i'm doing something wrong.

I need to rewrite this kind of url: 
this is the FROM url :

```
http://website.com/a-section-a/a-section-b/a-section-c/99999-name-name2#
```

to: 
this is the TO url :

```
http://website.com/index.php/newsection/99999-name-name2
```

I tried many thing but actually i get it:

```
RewriteRule /index.php/newsection/ \/([a-z]+([-]|[\/]))+
```

But not working ( rewrite engine ON ).

edit : The url should redirect to the TO page AND rewrite it.

Comment: Not clear which one is `TO` and which one is `FROM`, because your rule seems to indicate that `newsection` is `FROM`, which contradicts what you said earlier. Please clarify: What url does the user click on? Where should it redirect / be rewritten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit unclear on how your rewrite rule should work due to your syntax and the odd placement of `/index.php/`, but try using this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/(.*)?$ /index.php/newsection/$4 [R,L,NC]
```

Just so you understand how it works, the `RewriteEngine On` simply tells Apache to turn on the rewrite rule engine in the ruleset. The `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` assures the rule only kicks in of there isn’t a file with the same name. Similarly, the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` assures that the rule does not kick in if there isn’t a directory with the same name.

Now the actual `RewriteRule` breaks down like this:

- Each `([a-z0-9-]+)` represents a segment of the URL path. It only matches the letters a-z (case insensitive) & numbers 0-9 as well as the `-` character.
- The `/` designates each path part like a real URL.
- The last part of the path is `(.*)?$` which will catch anything`.
- The area past the regex stuff that matches the URL is the redirect destination with `$4` matching the last thing captured by the regex stuff.
- And the `[R,L,NC]` are Apache rewrite rule flags that equate to: `R` means redirect, `L` means last meaning the ruleset stops processing & `NC` means match the rule with “no case” (aka: case-insensitive).

Comment: Thanks ! it perfectly work !
I'll do some research to understand why it's working but it's perfect !

Answer (score -1):

try below code,

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9} /index.html HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index.html$ http://www.yoursite.com/ [R=301,L]
```